# Transfer records from MS Access to MY-Sql client as a scheduled task

Tags: java, mysql, ms-access

I have a MS-Access Database which is connected with  a Delphi application. So I can not manually edit the database. 
Daily that database will be added with new recorders, for eg. " Orders "
Note - This database can only conclude only 100 days records

Currently I am developing a Java Desktop based application to use instead of that Delphi application except some functionalities. 
For this Java application I am using My-Sql client Database.

For a reason, I need to put each day records which created in MS-Access database to My-Sql database in  the same table as updating the table with Auto increment.
I want to make this action as a schedule to run daily at 23.30

I have researched a lot for this and even posted a question here too(in a different approach) and couldn't find a solution to make this....

Note - Exporting also, I tried

Tried to make it through a separate Java application but couldn't get the appropriate date type to search through "Date" column in MS Access.

```
 LocalDate  date = LocalDate.now(); 
 System.out.println(date);
 LocalDate  dat = date.minusDays(21); 

 java.sql.Date date1 = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
 Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date1.getTime());
 System.out.println(timestamp);

PreparedStatement pstm = li.prepareStatement("SELECT BID,Datum,Sum FROM Bestellung WHERE Datum = ? "); 
pstm.setObject(1, Date.valueOf(dat));
ResultSet Rs = pstm.executeQuery();
```

Comment: If you've done a lot of research and posted a question, show it! What's your most promising approach, what have you tried and didn't work, etc. We don't want to repeat something you've already tried and which failed.

Comment: Actually i was tried to write a scheduled task in Java as a separate application to fetch new records and insert in to a Mysql. But in ucanaccess driver has some Date mismatch errors in Java.Time. So it didnt work out on my thing because the date column in my database is type "Date/Time"

Comment: Show the code! That sounds like a trivial to fix bug

Comment: java.sql.Date date1 = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
 Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date1.getTime());

Comment: pstm.setObject(1, timestamp);

Comment: Edit question to show code there.